# How to create a chart in sumo logic which shows on what days has throttling occurred in the account?

Tags: sumologic

Our account is throttled occasionally. We do not want to set up alerts due to budget constraints. However, we want to create a chart which can tell if throttling has occurred on a given day. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to have a complete suggestion without seeing your data, but...

My general suggestion is to:

- format the date you are having with `| formatDate` operator
- in the formatting String make sure to include the day of week (`EEE` or similar)
- then `| group by` on this formatted date

Some docs which are related to your need (although not exactly what you are after):

- https://help.sumologic.com/docs/search/search-query-language/search-operators/formatdate/#messages-by-day-of-the-week

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by Sumo Logic.